# finding consecutive values greater than a threshold

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
YEARMONTH   UNITS_SOLD
     
 2020-01      5
 2020-02      10
 2020-03      10
 2020-04      5
 2020-05      5
 2020-06      5
 2020-07      10
 2020-08      10
```

I am looking to find the rows where there is 2 or more instances where `NUM_UNITS` sold is `>=10` and mark the first instance of such an occurrence as `True` in a `marker` column.
So my result I am trying to achieve is

`````
YEARMONTH   UNITS_SOLD    Marker
     
 2020-01      5           False
 2020-02      10          True
 2020-03      10          False
 2020-04      5           False
 2020-05      5           False
 2020-06      5           False
 2020-07      10          True
 2020-08      10          False 
````
Not sure how to proceed here...any inputs will be appreciated.
Thanks!
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `cumsum` create the sub group key

```
s = df.UNITS_SOLD.lt(10).cumsum()
out = df[df.UNITS_SOLD.ge(10)].groupby(s)['UNITS_SOLD'].transform('count')
df['Maker'] = df.index.isin(out[out>=2].groupby(s).idxmin())
df
Out[159]: 
  YEARMONTH  UNITS_SOLD  Maker
0   2020-01           5  False
1   2020-02          10   True
2   2020-03          10  False
3   2020-04           5  False
4   2020-05           5  False
5   2020-06           5  False
6   2020-07          10   True
7   2020-08          10  False
```

Comment: Hi. Could you hint how to do the same, but applied to LAST instance of occurence (instead of first)? I tried few options, but a bit stuck.